# 8 channel pass through on Behringer XAir XR18

Tags: field-recording, mixer, behringer

I am trying to use a Behringer XR18 as a passthrough for recording and live sound.

I want route 8 channels from the 8 inputs to 8 outputs for the sound guy while recording 8 channels to Reaper through the USB. I'd like to leave the sound guy completely responsible for FOH and monitors at this point.

There are 6 Aux XLR outputs and 2 XLRs for Main L and Main R. In XAir Edit I can see how to route the first 6 inputs to the 6 Aux outputs with the Aux In/Out menu.

How do I route input channels 7 & 8 to the Main L and Main R outputs?  I don't see input channel routing options in the Main I/Out menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to route channels 7 and 8 to the mains is to pan them on to each side and push them up like you were mixing FOH for a show. Set the aux channels to pre-fader and then turn them up in the aux. Use 7 and 8 like you are mixing normal and pan them and push the faders up to where you want.

Comment: Note that although this will route 8 individual channels out of the XR18 the receiving mixer must be able to accept each channel as a ‘Line-In’ signal; this can require special cables for older mixers and is not the preferred method to send signal to the FOH mixer. I would not be happy if someone did this to me.

Comment: @Timinycricket  Where are you getting your information from?  All XLR outputs on the XR18 are low impedance as specified at https://behringerwiki.musictribe.com/index.php?title=9.1_X18/XR18_Specifications

Comment: impedance and voltage are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-starter I'm afraid.

Your best bet is to simply acquire or make 8 passive splits and split the input channels prior to the XR18. Send the splits to the FOH/Monitor engineer.